# Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I dont understand why my app crashed when install apk?
I want click on actionbutton and next to call
logcat:

```
08-19 17:26:06.466 15592-15954/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
08-19 17:26:06.332 15592-15592/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
08-19 17:26:06.332 15592-15592/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
```

main_activity.java

```
   public void Call(View v)
    {
        Intent intentcall= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:103"));
        startActivity(intentcall);

    }
```

xml:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:onClick="Call"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your method, it works perfectly. Syntax is correct, fab has not error. The fact of your app crash on installing apk looks like an Android Studio's failure because of the "Fast Run" function ([see...](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run)).

Try installing after stop your app by closing it (if it is already running) and/or clicking in the red stop button.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DILIQ.png)

Comment: Is this a solution?

Comment: Maybe someday it could be the solution :J